# READING stderr from within Awk

Tags: awk, redirect, string-matching

I want to keep SSH debug info separate (and logged) from other input. However, if I simply redirect stderr to a log file, I risk combining output from SSH and output from the remote process on the host machine (that *might* send something to stderr):

```
$ ssh -v somemachine 2> file.log
```

So, I want to filter out only those lines that match "debug1":

```
$ ssh -v somemachine | awk '/debug1/ {print > "file.log"; next} {print}'
```

Good so far, BUT ssh's debug output goes to stderr. So...

```
$ ssh -v somemachine 2>& | awk '/debug1/ {print > "file.log"; next} {print}'
```

Foiled again! I don't want to mix stdout and stderr. BAD!

What does a kid like me do? I was about to go the route of named pipes or some such wildness, but really, all I need to know is how to get awk to match patterns from stderr ONLY.

Comment: By the point that you introduced /debug1/ into your pipeline, you've stepped out of what the pipe model expects. Is there a reason you can't log stderr on the remote session?

Comment: Note that awk only reads named files or standard input; it does not read stderr.  So, you have to arrange for what it does read to be the 'ssh' stderr output.

Comment: I only want to log stderr message from ssh itself and still allow other stderr messages to be seen. I will be running a command remotely with ssh:

$ ssh -v somemachine somecommand

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Awk can't actually see the input from stderr - the pipe only pipes stdout. You're going to have to muck about with redirection in order to do what you want. The answer is really simple if you don't care about what's on stdout:

```
(ssh -v hostname somecommand > /dev/null) 2>&1 | awk '/debug1/ ...'
```

If you care about what's on stdout, you'll have to do something more complex. I believe that this will work:

```
((ssh -v hostname somecommand 1>&3) 2>&1 | awk '/debug1/ ...' 1>&2) 3>&1
```

In order, those redirects:

- redirect the original stdout aside to file descriptor 3
- redirect stderr to stdout for awk to see
- redirect stdout back to stderr (where it originally was)
- redirect file descriptor 3 back to stdout (where it originally was)

P.S. This solution is sh/bash-specific. Jonathan Leffler says it should work with ksh as well. If you're using a different shell, you can try to find the syntax to do the same redirects with it - but if that different shell is csh/tcsh, you're probably just screwed. The cshells are notoriously bad at handling stdout/stderr.

Comment: The solution should work on Bourne and Korn shells too; it's the decorative sea shells that will have problems.  And that's why you're best off leaving the C shells on the sea shore where, hopefully, the tide will take them away.

Comment: Can you avoid the double sub-shell and do the: `1>&3` and `2>&1` redirects at the same time - in that order?

Comment: @Jonathan: I don't think so. This was my test: `(./foo | sed 's/^/stdout: /' 1>&3  2>&1 | sed 's/^/stderr: /' 1>&2) 3>&1` where `foo` echoes one line each to stdout and stderr. Without the extra sub-shell there, the stderr line appears to pass through cleanly, as if the 2>&1 redirect happened first - I guess there's no guarantee about the order being preserved?

Comment: My bad - when you use the one sub-shell, the order is preserved, but... 1 goes to 3, and then 2 goes to where 1 is going - which is also 3.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try (no subshells):

```
{ ssh -v somemachine 2>&1 1>&3- | awk '/debug1/ {print > "file.log"; next} {print}'; } 3>&1
```

or

```
{ ssh -v somemachine 2>&1 1>&3- | grep debug1 > file.log; } 3>&1
```

See [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/047).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot..! I used ls with awk and was not able to redirect.

I used:

```
FILES=`ls -lrt *.txt | awk '{print $9}' 2>> /dev/null`
```

Now:

```
FILES=`ls -lrt *.txt 2>> /dev/null | awk '{print $9}'`
```